# Invasion of the Body Snatchers - rationale

Tags: body-snatchers

What would have been the body snatchers' purpose in replacing humans and leading their lives, once they did not have to try to look like humans anymore?

Once all humans which could be replaced were replaced, there was no sense in trying to lead humans lives - or was there?

Comment: In which version? Or both?

Comment: When did they ever reach the point where all humans were replaced?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - At the end of the 1978 version with the famous "scream" scene, I would imagine

Comment: The answer is probably we will never know, since we won't be around to witness.

Comment: @Valorum - the entire point of the "scream" is to alert the others that they found a human, so..... by definition, not all replaced at that point.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - Like I said, this is probably the scene that OP is referencing, in which case the *rationale* is to trick un-snatched humans into revealing themselves.

Comment: I read somewhere that what was really horrifying about the ending was that when Donald Sutherland let out the 'pod scream' he was actually still human. The horror of it was that he was "going along to get along", and he was afraid his friend was going to give him away. I think I read that in "Future Tense" by John Brosnan, or some other book.

Comment: @theguest - no, I don't think that's right, at all.  The terror is that, while his friend thought he was faking, like she was, the horrific discovery was that he *wasn't* faking, and had been replaced by a pod-alien.

Comment: @Valorum - if you look at OP's wording, "once all humans which could be replaced were replace, there ***was*** no sense in trying to lead human lives" - that seems to imply that all humans were replaced, since any non-replaced human could be replaced if caught. My problem is that this seems to imply that we've seen a status where all humans were assimilated, and they still acted like humans. We never reached that point in the story. So, in answer to my question, "when did they ever reach the point?" you saying the rationale was to trick other humans is also saying they didn't reach that point.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - To risk repeating my earlier point, we see an entire town full of pod people going about their normal everyday (human) lives at the end of the film.  I suspect that that is what OP is referring to in their question but since they're being uncommunicative, we may not find out.

Answer (score 4):

In the novel their one purpose is 'to survive' p224, and they return to space looking for a less 'fierce and inhospitable planet' The Body Snatchers by Jack Finney (1955) Chapter 21, p223. [While the narrator's opinion, the implication of the text is that he is somehow in touch with their intent, and feels their departure.] It is however clear that they can 'reseed' space.

Given 'survival' as a goal, and seeding as the mechanism, imitation of animal/human life is only a biological stage - not an end - so speculatively, once having replaced humanity, they would replace animals and plants too until they were the whole biosphere and then spore spreading on to other worlds. [The sporing stage would probably slough off human appearances growing to the size of St. Paul's cathedral. I base the latter on the biology of the Krynoids in Doctor Who (influenced by Finney's body snatchers, and Nigel Kneale's Quatermass Experiment (1955 contemporary with novel)]

Comment: There's no real purpose.  It's just the way their biology works, it's what they do.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple reason is that this is the best way to continue to survive on the planet whose dominant species they have replaced -- to have human capabilities to plant crops, even do business -- all the things necessary to keep things running smoothly until they manage to send out spores to another planet.

Speculating, they may be more advanced than humans, carrying the knowledge of other species they have replaced and perhaps they will continue and accelerate our space and astronomy programs in an effort to find other planets to from their of view to colonize.

I see that the wikipedia article says that the book indicates they aliens live only 5 years and I am not sure how civilization would be able to continue with that sort of urgent time table.